# Create and fill an Access Database from native C++

Tags: c++, database, ms-access, native

I'm a hydrologist who has learned C++ to build and extend a urban-hydrology model.

The programmer I work with and myself just made the model fully grid-based/distributed (verus statistically distributed), and now we have data storage problems because we are dealing with grid approximately 500 x 500 cells across 8000+ timesteps, and we are storing 10+ values for each cell's timestep.

So, we are switching from double vector storage to database storage, but are trying to find a native solution for creating and filling a access database.  Native solution, to avoid Visual C++, to simplify things for my sake.  And, I'm asking for help cause we are having trouble finding a solution.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what your question is. Do you have a specific issue with the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "native C++". As @ThomasMatthews suggests in his answer, given that Access is a Windows application one would think that Microsoft Visual C++ would be as "native" as you can get. Do you really mean "GNU C++", or perhaps some/any other *non-Microsoft* implementation?

Comment: If you are searching for some cross-platform solution, I'd recommend you to use SQLAPI++ (https://www.sqlapi.com/).

Answer (score 0):

"Native" connection to a database depends on the database vendor.

You have the tag for MS-Access, and yet you don't want to use Visual C++.  I believe that Visual C++ has been tweaked to provide efficient and easy access to the MS-Access database, maybe even using non-standard communication methods.

Search the web for "MSDN C++ Access ODBC".